# Trying to understand a formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with the following formula: `=R3*$S$3+T2`. What does `$S$3` mean?

Answer (score 4):

The `$`s are 'anchors'. Copy the formula down one row (for example) and it becomes:

```
=R4*$S$3+T3
```

Copy that across one column (usually to the right) and it becomes:

```
 =S4*$S$3+U3
```

So `$S$3` stays as the multiplier for the first reference. Were the content of `S3` say `53` then the above could be written: `=R4*53+T3` and `=S4*53+U3` respectively for the same results.

`$`s indicate fixed rather than the more usual relative references, with the choice being to anchor the row `C$n`, or the column `$aR`, or both (as above).